# ping + how to minimize the time of the ping command

Tags: linux, bash, solaris, ping

I want to create bash script that will verify by ping list of IP’s

The problem is that ping to any address take few seconds ( in case no ping answer ) in spite I defined the ping as the following:

```
Ping –c  1 126.78.6.23
```

The example above perform ping only one time – but the problem is the time , waiting few seconds until ping ended ( if no answer )

In my case this is critical because I need to check more than 150 IP’s ( usually more 90% of the IP’s are not alive )

So to check 150 IP’s I need more than 500 seconds

Please advice if there is some good idea how to perform ping quickly

- remark my script need to run on both OS ( linux and solaris )

Comment: this has already been answered on SU - http://superuser.com/questions/264254/how-can-i-get-ping-timeout-below-1-second

Comment: enter in the link provided by Bartlomiej, there's the answer

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski, I am not sure that is asking the right question.  I kinda suspect he is looking for a method for parallel processing, a low response time.

Comment: I would be probably be tempted to use `nmap -sP` and enable some of the options to enable parallel processing.

Comment: `nmap` is the approach I would take as well. Why reinvent the wheel when something else will do the job for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best idea is to run ping in parallel
and then save the result in a file.
In this case your script will run not longer than a second.

```
for ip in `< list`
do
   ( ping -c1 $ip || echo ip >> not-reachable ) &
done
```

**Update.** In Solaris `-c` has other meaning, so for solaris you need 
run `ping` other way:

```
ping $ip 57 1
```

(Here, 57 is the size of the packet and 1 is the number of the packets to be sent).

Ping's syntax in Solaris:

```
/usr/sbin/ping -s [-l | -U] [-adlLnrRv] [-A addr_family]
  [-c traffic_class] [-g gateway [ -g gateway...]]
  [-F flow_label] [-I interval] [-i interface] [-P tos]
  [-p port] [-t ttl] host [data_size] [npackets]
```

You can make a function that aggregates the two methods:

```
myping()
{
   [ `uname` = Linux ] && ping -c 1 "$i" || ping "$ip" 57 1
}
for ip in `< list`
do
   ( myping $ip || echo ip >> not-reachable ) &
done
```

Another option, don't use `ping` directly but use ICMP module from some language.
You can use for example Perl + `Net::Ping` module from Perl:

```
perl -e 'use Net::Ping; $timeout=0.5; $p=Net::Ping->new("icmp", $timeout) or die bye ; print "$host is alive \n" if $p->ping($host); $p->close;'
```

Comment: for solaris -c1 isnt valid

Comment: @Eytan: In the perl command, you have an ip in the `$host` variable

Answer (score 1):

Does Solaris ship with `coreutils` OOTB these days? Then you can use `timeout` to specify an upper limit:

```
timeout 0.2s ping -c 1 www.doesnot.exist >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [hping3](http://www.hping.org/), which is scriptable (in Tcl).

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, a simple way is to overcome the timing issue run the ping commands in parallel.

You already have the syntax for Linux (iputils) ping.

With Solaris, the proper option to send a single ping would be

```
ping -s 126.78.6.23 64 1
```

Installing [nmap from sources](http://nmap.org/book/inst-source.html) would provide a more powerful alternative though.